# Leave an answer on popular question with already accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While reviewing late answers, I see a lot of cases when people write an answer on popular questions with already accepted answer. Also, I've walk through a some high-viewed questions and noticed that there are few users that leave the same answer as accepted one (same by meaning, not equal at all) just for extra rating points. Is it allowed?

Comment: Allowed: sure. But, imo, if you don't have nothing new to add, don't try to piggyback onto someone's popular post like that.

Comment: Agree. But now it's just like unspoken rule.

Comment: It's happening not only for late answers. Note that the phenomenon is caused by people who upvote such answers, not by people who provide them. It may look strangely, but it means that there is demand for such answers. Maybe people want to reinforce accepted answers in this way.

Comment: Legally, there is nothing wrong posting same answer. Ethically, it's little wrong. Well we are know that posting same answer in popular questions just for taking attention.

Comment: @howaboutNO posting a copy of an older answer is a [meta-tag:plagiarism]; moderators delete this stuff as soon as they get notified of it

Comment: @gnat I've noticed, not the plagiarizm. Same by meaning, but not equal by content.

Comment: I see. This is a problem too, especially at SO which doesn't have firm norms on "don't repeat others". You may be interested in this MSE discussion: [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)